# Symfony2 - adding form for oneToMany strange rendering with a "0"

Tags: forms, symfony, one-to-many, zero

I have a form which works fine. It persists data to two entities (News and Illustration). In fact, it will be possible, in a near future, that the user can add multiple illustrations to the news. BUT, not now :)...

So i've the backend ready for this and when I run the action which calls the formbuilder which builds the form with two FormTypes:

```
class NewsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder
            ->add('date', 'date')
            ->add('titre', 'text')
            ->add('contenu', 'textarea')
            ->add('publication', 'checkbox', array('required' => false))
            ->add('illustrations', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new IllustrationType(), 
                'allow_add' => false,
                'required' => false 
            ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'News';
    }
} 

class IllustrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder
            ->add('file', 'file');
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Fcbg\NewsBundle\Entity\Illustration',
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Illustration';
    }
}
```

The form output renders something like that:

[image: screenshot of the strage zero]

Some idea why I have the "illustrations: 0" ? XD

Thx a lot

Comment: It's the number of your first collection. Look at the collection_widget from fields.html.twig from Symfony twig component to manage render or add some javascript to manage multiple insert of files

Answer (score 0):

You see this because you didn't say how many Illustration you want to display (1? 2? 0? 100?). In doubt, Symfony chose to display none.

Either you allow the user to create one or several new Illustration by setting `'allow_add' => true,` (what you don't want to do yet, I understood), or you manually create one (or even several) `Illustration` in your NewsController.php:

```
public function addAction()
 {
        $news = new News();

        $Illustration = new Illustration();
        $news->addIllustration($illustration);

        // create your form and display it
 }
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean... but is it not possible just to hide the information (not by javascript hum :D)

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted to have one and only one. If you don't want to see anything and keep your code ready for future evolution, just comment the `->add('illustrations', 'collection',[..]` lines!